# If $X$ be compact set is $\overline X$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ be compact set are $\overline X$, the closure of $X$, compact? and how to prove that compact set in a topological set need not be closed?

Comment: Do you make any assumptions on the underlying topological space? An example: finite sets are always compact, but need not be closed.

Comment: In the trivial topology on a large enough set, all subsets are compact and most are not closed.

Comment: I guess "$X$ compact $\Rightarrow \bar{X}$ compact" follows from topology axiomatic.

Answer (score 4):

No, this property doesn't hold in general.  Take any noncompact space $Y$, and topologize $Y' = Y\coprod \{p\}$ so that $\overline{\{p\}} = Y'$.

It does hold in Hausdorff spaces, because compact sets are already closed.  And it's true under more general assumptions akin to local compactness.  But as we've seen above, closure can be a very non-local operation without some assumptions.